# How does Node.js know to render ejs in views folder

Tags: node.js

I am currently new and learning Node.js and web development in general, and in a route when I render an ejs file, the code would be something like: res.render("index").

Index.ejs would be in a folder called views. How does Node know to look into my views subfolder ( from the project/ parent folder)?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what nodejs framework you are using.
If you are using **expressjs** framework then you can tell your app.js the location of the **views** folder by doing the following.

```js
//in app.js

app.set('views', config.root + '/app/views')
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
```

And the views can then be rendered in the **routes.js** file like this.

```js
// in routes.js
module.exports = function (app) {
  // home route
  app.get('/', home.index)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Node, there is something called **Template Engine**. A template engine enables you to use static template files in your application at runtime, the template engine replaces variables in a template file with actual values, and transforms the template into an HTML file sent to the client

If you are using express js you can first set the view engine like this

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

And then in your routes, you can do like this

```
app.get('/new.html', function(req,res) {
    res.render('new.html');
});
```

Note that the template engines that work with Express are Pug, Mustache, and EJS. The Express application generator uses Jade as its default, but it also supports several others.

Comment: Yes, I am using express. So "app.set('view engine', 'ejs') is the line of code that tells the template engine to look in the views folder for ejs?

Comment: You didn't answer the question asked: *"How does Node know to look into my views subfolder".*

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **expressjs** and **ejs** template engine
The "**app.set("view engine", ejs)**" automatically detects the **ejs** files
But you can change the default directory for your views

Comment: In my case, I don't have: `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` and it automatically picked up ejs files from the /views directory. So this answers the question

Answer (score 1):

There must be a predefined configuration for the `views` folder.

e.g: If you're using Express.js you can set the views like this:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding forward slash **(/)** following the **folder-name** like:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
     res.render("foldername/index");
});
```